# Xml reader - (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc, xmlreader

I use Xml reader to read some blogs feed like this:

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
```

I'm getting an error with some urls:

> {"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}

If I open this url in my browser it works well.

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The *web server* denied anonymous access to you. This has nothing at all to do with XML or XmlReader.

Comment: Download Fiddler and see what the full response from the server is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply credentials for the `XmlReader` to use when accessing a URL; which is likely what you need to do in your circumstance.  see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47as68k4(v=vs.71).aspx for details.

You could also use an `HttpClient` object with credentials to get the response as a `Stream` and use `XmlReader.Create(Stream)` instead.